# Unable to run any child processes with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install packages for a work repo, however whenever I try to run the install, once it gets to the child processes (like running install scripts for a package) I get a weird spawn error. I'm assuming it's having issues running the child processes.

Some information:

- Windows machine
- Node v12.22.3 and npm v6.14.13 (I've tried node 14)
- Tried using bash, windows terminal, cmd prompt, and powershell (all with admin)
- Error code seems to be a 4058 but I'm not sure what it can't find

It was working fine just last week, now suddenly I can't get anything done. I've tried the following:

- Turning off the Work AV
- Removing `node_modules` and `package-lock`
- Running `npm cache clear --force` and `npm cache verify`
- Uninstalling node and reinstalling
- Completely uninstalling nvm and node and reinstalling

The error I see is:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn =
npm ERR! file =
npm ERR! path =
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! root@ prepare: `husky install`
npm ERR! spawn = ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the root@ prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dhers\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-19T18_28_56_807Z-debug.log
```

Do note this is **NOT** a husky problem, anything that runs a child process script seems to have this error happen.

I've never seen this before and I'm unable to fix it with the googling I've done. Here is some information from the npm log:

```
59 silly lifecycle root@~prepare: Args: [ '-c', 'husky install' ]
60 info lifecycle root@~prepare: Failed to exec prepare script
61 silly lifecycle root@~prepare: Returned: code: -4058  signal: null
62 info lifecycle root@~prepare: Failed to exec prepare script
63 verbose stack Error: root@ prepare: `husky install`
63 verbose stack spawn = ENOENT
63 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
63 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
63 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
64 verbose pkgid root@
65 verbose cwd C:\Users\dhers\Documents\Development\Work\seamless
66 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
67 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
68 verbose node v12.22.3
69 verbose npm  v6.14.13
```

Has anyone seen this before? I'm really hoping I'm just overlooking something super simple. Any help would be appreciated because this has me halted right now.

Comment: As of 7/27/2021 this problem still persists :(

Comment: when I had these kind of weird errors yarn saved my time and nerves. Try to use yarn, maybe it could help

Comment: Did you try deleting your entire local clone and re-cloning?

Comment: I sure did, I wiped the entire folder structure even

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the following:

1. Clean the `npm` cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2. Check the npm version you're using. Maybe it should be updated:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

3. Try with another version of the package [`huskey`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky)
4. For this specific scenario, try to skip `huskey install` through adding

```
export HUSKY_SKIP_INSTALL=true
```

to the npm install cmd just to see whether the problem persists with other **prepare** scripts.

5. Add the script to the **postinstall** hook instead of the **prepare** hook to see if the problem is from the hook.
6. Go up level by level in your working directory and make sure there are no other directories containing `/node_modules` directory or `package.json` or a `pakcage-lock.json` file. Sometimes `npm` considers it the root of the project.

Comment: I tried most of these steps, and it is NOT a husky only issue, as the problem persists with other libraries that run similar scripts no matter what step they run at I see this issue.

Comment: Did anyone in your team run into the same problem?

Comment: No, I'm the first one. But I'm also the first dev to be running a native windows laptop (it lured me in with that sweet sweet RTX) I'm running the linux subsystem right now, and that's allowing me to work around this issue as everything is working fine there.

Comment: @dhershman I added another potential solution to my answer. Give it a try. Sometimes it happens in windows. I happened with some people I know before.

Comment: @dhershman did you try solution 6? Try looking for `/node-modules` or `package-lock.json` until you reach `C:`. It happened with one of my students before and it drove him crazy.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately everything is as it should be after diving and digging through the system looking for it I couldn't find anything outside my work directories.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **system** environment variables PATH contains the following values:

> %SystemRoot%
>
> %SystemRoot%\system32
>
> %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Also, make sure your **User** environment variables PATH contains the following value:

> C:\Users\dhers\AppData\Roaming\npm

Note that you need to restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This was a no go as well :( I thought we were onto something with this one too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`

Execute `npm cache clean --force`

Execute `npm install` or `yarn install`

Then again run

maybe the wrong is your dependencies, check in your package.json
and your npm local is not the correct

```
"dependencies": {
  "npm": "^7.5.6",
```

then you can try with yarn, `yarn install`